# Dynamics nav use tables and functions from a created extension in a new extension

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, nav

I created with AL a App for Dynamics nav as a base app and now I want to extend it with a new AL project.

Is there a way that I can use functions and tables from my base app in my new extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just follow these steps:

- Publish your base app.
- Add it to the dependencies in your app.json of
  the new app.
- Download the symbols.
- Publish your new Al project.